# openCV face detection opencv_core2410d.pdb error

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying out face detection using `OpenCV` and am pretty new to `OpenCV`.

Here's my code:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>


#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


static void read_csv(const string& filename, vector<Mat>& images,         vector<int>& labels, char separator = ';') {
std::ifstream file(filename.c_str(), ifstream::in);
if (!file) {
    string error_message = "No valid input file was given, please check the given filename.";
    CV_Error(CV_StsBadArg, error_message);
}
string line, path, classlabel;
while (getline(file, line)) {
    stringstream liness(line);
    getline(liness, path, separator);
    getline(liness, classlabel);
    if (!path.empty() && !classlabel.empty()) {
        images.push_back(imread(path, 0));
        labels.push_back(atoi(classlabel.c_str()));
    }
}
}


int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {

string fn_haar = "haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml";
string fn_csv = "reader.txt";
int deviceId = 0;

// These vectors hold the images and corresponding labels:
vector<Mat> images;
vector<int> labels;


try {
    read_csv(fn_csv, images, labels);
}
catch (cv::Exception& e) {
    cerr << "Error opening file \"" << fn_csv << "\". Reason: " << e.msg << endl;
    // nothing more we can do
    exit(1);
}


int im_width = images[0].cols;
int im_height = images[0].rows;

Ptr<FaceRecognizer> model = createFisherFaceRecognizer();
model->train(images, labels);


CascadeClassifier haar_cascade;
haar_cascade.load(fn_haar);

VideoCapture cap(deviceId);

if (!cap.isOpened()) {
    cerr << "Capture Device ID " << deviceId << "cannot be opened." << endl;
    return -1;
}

Mat frame;
while (true) {
    cap >> frame;

    Mat original = frame.clone();

    Mat gray;
    cvtColor(original, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    vector< Rect_<int> > faces;
    haar_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, faces);

    for (int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++) {

        Rect face_i = faces[i];

        Mat face = gray(face_i);

        Mat face_resized;
        cv::resize(face, face_resized, Size(im_width, im_height), 1.0, 1.0, INTER_CUBIC);

        int prediction = model->predict(face_resized);

        rectangle(original, face_i, CV_RGB(0, 255, 0), 1);

        string box_text = format("Prediction = %d", prediction);

        int pos_x = std::max(face_i.tl().x - 10, 0);
        int pos_y = std::max(face_i.tl().y - 10, 0);

        putText(original, box_text, Point(pos_x, pos_y), FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1.0, CV_RGB(0, 255, 0), 2.0);
    }

    namedWindow("face_recognizer", 1);


    imshow("face_recognizer", original);

    char key = (char)waitKey(20);

    if (key == 27)
        break;

}
return 0;
}
```

And here's my reader.txt file

```
C:\Users\Hitanshu Dhawan\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication21\ConsoleApplication21\obama\obama1.jpg;0
C:\Users\Hitanshu Dhawan\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication21\ConsoleApplication21\obama\obama2.jpg;0
```

Now, the problem is my code is not working and it shows some error "Exception at memory location" and "Integer division by zero" and "opencv_core2410d.pdb not loaded"...

I've tried many ways such as adding different lib in `Linker > Input`.
Also I've checked the Microsoft Symbol Servers.
Also my `.xml` and `.csv` files are properly copied into the application folder!

Here are some screenshots:

[image: integer division by zero screenshot]

[image: opencv_core2410d.pdb error]

Comment: Please don't link to error messages as images. It's better if you would include them in the question itself.

Comment: Same error for me. With this error, I cannot find where is the error in my code.

Comment: yup, i am still unable to detect the problem..if you are able ro do it please inform me